# How to replace multiple values to one in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, gis, geo

I am currently trying to get countries from rows of data frame. Here is the code that i currently have:

```
l = [
 ['[Aydemir, Deniz\', \' Gunduz, Gokhan\', \' Asik, Nejla] Bartin 
   Univ, Fac Forestry, Dept Forest Ind Engn, TR-74100 Bartin, 
   Turkey\', \' [Wang, Alice] Lulea Univ Technol, Wood Technol, 
   Skelleftea, Sweden',1990],
 ['[Fang, Qun\', \' Cui, Hui-Wang] Zhejiang A&F Univ, Sch Engn, Linan 
   311300, Peoples R China\', \' [Du, Guan-Ben] Southwest Forestry 
   Univ, Kunming 650224, Yunnan, Peoples R China',2005],
 ['[Blumentritt, Melanie\', \' Gardner, Douglas J.\', \' Shaler 
   Stephen M.] Univ Maine, Sch Resources, Orono, ME USA\', \' [Cole, 
   Barbara J. W.] Univ Maine, Dept Chem, Orono, ME 04469 USA',2012],
 ['[Kyvelou, Pinelopi; Gardner, Leroy; Nethercot, David A.] Univ 
   London Imperial Coll Sci Technol & Med, London SW7 2AZ, 
   England',1998]]
dataf = pd.DataFrame(l, columns = ['Authors', 'Year'])
```

This is the data frame. And here is the code:

```
df = (dataf['Authors']
  .replace(r"\bUSA\b", "United States", regex=True)
  .apply(lambda x: geotext.GeoText(x).countries))
```

The problem was that GeoText didn't recognize "USA", but now I also saw that I need to change "England", "Scotland", "Wales" and "Northern Ireland" to "United Kingdom". 
How can I extend `.replace` to achieve this?

Comment: Try to format the arrays better, its incredibly hard to read it like that

Comment: Multiple `replace`s? I.e. `dataf['Authors'].replace(...).replace(...).apply(...)`

Comment: @A.J.Uppal I was thinking if there is another way, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `translate` method of the `Series.str` module and pass a dictionary of replacements.

```
dataf.Authors.str.translate({
    'USA': 'United States', 
    "England": "United Kingdom", 
    "Scotland": "United Kingdom", 
    "Wales": "United Kingdom",
    "Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom"
})
```

Comment: Can I add `.apply(lambda x: geotext.GeoText(x).countries))` at the end of that?

Comment: Yes, I don't see why not.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Here is the code:

```
replace_list = ['England', 'Scotland', 'Wales', 'Northern Ireland']
for check in replace_list:
    dataf['Authors'] = dataf['Authors'].str.replace(check, 'United Kingdom', regex=True)
```